# Store MiniProfiler results in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, mvc-mini-profiler, miniprofiler

I have integrated MiniProfiler v4.2.22 in my Asp.Net Core application.

Its is working as expected when using In-Memory database, but when i change the storage option to PostgreSQL or SQL Server, no data is coming in the results.

Code Used -

```
services.AddMiniProfiler(options =>
{
    options.UserIdProvider = (request) =>
    {
        var id = request.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value ?? request.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("sub")?.Value;
        return id;
    };

    options.RouteBasePath = "/profiler"; 
    options.PopupRenderPosition = StackExchange.Profiling.RenderPosition.BottomLeft;
    options.PopupShowTimeWithChildren = true;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(miniProfilerOptions?.PostgreSqlStorage?.ConectionString))
    {
        var storageOpt = miniProfilerOptions.PostgreSqlStorage;
        var storage = new PostgreSqlStorage(storageOpt.ConectionString, storageOpt.ProfilersTable, storageOpt.TimingsTable, storageOpt.ClientTimingsTable);
        _ = storage.TableCreationScripts;

        options.Storage = storage;
    }                   

    options.ShouldProfile = (request) =>
    {
        if (request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/healthcheck"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    };
})
.AddEntityFramework();
```

appsettings.json -

```
"Monitoring": {
    "MiniProfiler": {
        "IsEnabled": true,
        "PostgreSqlStorage": {
            "ConectionString": "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=MiniProfilerTestDB;User ID=myLogin;Password=Password@1234567890;",
            "ProfilersTable": "MiniProfilersTable",
            "TimingsTable": "MiniProfilerTimingsTable",
            "ClientTimingsTable": "MiniProfilerClientTimingsTable"
        },
    },
}
```

Model -

```
public class MiniProfilerOptions
{
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

    public PostgreSqlStorageOptions PostgreSqlStorage { get; set; }
}

public class PostgreSqlStorageOptions
{
    public string ConectionString { get; set; }

    public string ProfilersTable { get; set; }

    public string TimingsTable { get; set; }

    public string ClientTimingsTable { get; set; }
}
```

SQL Query to create table -

```
CREATE TABLE "MiniProfilersTable"
(
    RowId                                serial primary key,
    Id                                   uuid not null, -- don't cluster on a guid
    RootTimingId                         uuid null,
    Name                                 varchar(200) null,
    Started                              timestamp(3) not null,
    DurationMilliseconds                 decimal(15,1) not null,
    "User"                               varchar(100) null,
    HasUserViewed                        boolean not null,
    MachineName                          varchar(100) null,
    CustomLinksJson                      varchar,
    ClientTimingsRedirectCount           integer null
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_MiniProfilersTable_Id ON "MiniProfilersTable" (Id);
            
CREATE INDEX IX_MiniProfilersTable_User_HasUserViewed_Includes ON "MiniProfilersTable" ("User", HasUserViewed);

CREATE TABLE "MiniProfilerTimingsTable"
(
    RowId                               serial primary key,
    Id                                  uuid not null,
    MiniProfilerId                      uuid not null,
    ParentTimingId                      uuid null,
    Name                                varchar(200) not null,
    DurationMilliseconds                decimal(15,3) not null,
    StartMilliseconds                   decimal(15,3) not null,
    IsRoot                              boolean not null,
    Depth                               smallint not null,
    CustomTimingsJson                   varchar null
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_MiniProfilerTimingsTable_Id ON "MiniProfilerTimingsTable" (Id);

CREATE INDEX IX_MiniProfilerTimingsTable_MiniProfilerId ON "MiniProfilerTimingsTable" (MiniProfilerId);

CREATE TABLE "MiniProfilerClientTimingsTable"
(
    RowId                               serial primary key,
    Id                                  uuid not null,
    MiniProfilerId                      uuid not null,
    Name                                varchar(200) not null,
    Start                               decimal(9, 3) not null,
    Duration                            decimal(9, 3) not null
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_MiniProfilerClientTimingsTable_Id on "MiniProfilerClientTimingsTable" (Id);

CREATE INDEX IX_MiniProfilerClientTimingsTable_MiniProfilerId on "MiniProfilerClientTimingsTable" (MiniProfilerId);
```

Am i doing something wrong ? or am i missing anything ?

Github Link - https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/issues/620

Comment: A side note: "*-- don't cluster on a guid*" - Postgres has no clustered indexes. So even if you define the `id` as the primary key you are not creating a clustered index. Btw: the standard compliant `identity` columns are recommended over `serial`

Comment: did you created database using this sql script or are you expecting an auto generation of database?

Comment: I have created the tables using SQL Script mentioned above. I got the script from (https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/main/src/MiniProfiler.Providers.PostgreSql/PostgreSqlStorage.cs)